# Remove Ubuntu 14.04 and install Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: system-installation, uninstall, software-uninstall, usb-installation

As the title says, i have Dell Inspiron 15 7559 pre-installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have no knowledge about Linux whatsoever because i've been using Windows for a long time. What i'm trying to say is, how do i remove Ubuntu 14.04 completely and install windows 7 Ultimate sp 1 version with USB? Please provide step by step from preparing the USB to Remove Ubuntu and Install windows 7. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove Ubuntu to install Windows, during windows installation bootup from disc you have the option to remove or format partitions and do a fresh install in it's place.

If you have no Windows installation disc then their is a way to create a flash drive installer: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/a/install-windows-7-usb.htm

Comment: Urm but i have no disc reader..i can only use usb

Answer (score 0):

Make your USB windows bootable, you can use [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) for that. Once you are done, connect that bootable USB to your system, go to BIOS, select USB as boot up device. When you are at **Install Windows screen**, press `Shift+f10`. Command prompt should open up.

Type `bootrec /fixmbr` into the Command Prompt. Then install windows.

After windows and all associated drivers are installed, go to `Disk management`, search for any Ubuntu partitions. Delete those and extend free space so that windows partitions can use that free space.

Comment: Ok now i've installed windows 7 ultimate on my dell. The problem is all drivers is not installed. Even the usb ports  and network adapter doesn't work.. what should i do now?